# I can't send email on my iMac

Tags: mail.app, email

I haven't been able to send email on my iMac for a while.  I've tried going into preferences and editing my outgoing server.  Each time I add password and make sure my user name and password are correct.  It allows me to hit ok but not save.  I'm frustrated and would appreciate any help.

Comment: what mail server are you using?

Comment: What mail app are you using?

Comment: I'm using the mail app on my iMac with cox webmail

Comment: Have you tried signing out from your accounts and then signing back in?

Comment: Finally!  But it won't save my changes.  Seems to automatically recheck the "maintain account settings" box even though I've unchecked it to type in log in and password on the outgoing server screen.  I get the "ok" screen there but then when closing preferences, it doesn't ask me to save it. So I'm stuck having to change it prior to writing and sending any email.